# After successfully moving our Magento installation, Magento doesn't log to /var/log anymore

Tags: php, magento, logging

We moved our Magento installation from one FreeBSD VPS server to another (8.2 to 10.0). After that, we can't see anything in Magentos `/var/log/system.log` anymore.

1. We have checked and re checked the permission (777) on `/var/log/*`
2. Whe have tried to enable logging in `/index.php`
3. We have checked the database => `dev/log/active` = 1
4. Whe have tried to change owner of `system.log` and `exception.log`

Where afraid something might be missing in PHP, maybe som extension? Or could it be permission on the local servers `/var/log` directory?

How can we produce an error, that should be logged to Magentos `/var/log` ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you root magento directory is writable and make sure apache user has permission to write file

Comment: This is what I got: drwxrwxrwx  19 root  wheel  1024 Feb 10 20:01 magento and drwxrwxrwx  11 myname  wheel   512 Feb  4 18:49 /magento/var

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to delete the old logs?

We had that problem - just renamed file and everything went okay.

Comment: Did you just change the name of the logfile in admin?

Comment: I did just rename it.
like: system.log_backup